# Android: "googleservices.json" is missing?

Tags: java, android, json

I am getting this execution error every time i am running the code and  'googleservices.json' is present in my app folder. My SDK version is also updated but still it giving error in these lines of code:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
```

Error Message:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot 
function without it. 
   Searched Location: 
  C:\Users\hp\AndroidStudioProjects\Friendly Chat\app\src\debug\google-
services.json
  C:\Users\hp\AndroidStudioProjects\Friendly Chat\app\google-services.json
```

And this is my build.gradle Code.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'

    // Displaying images
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin

Comment: make sure that its name is same as "google-services.json"

Comment: @WitVault Name is same. Still I'm getting this error.

Comment: Check the answer below which I have pasted and rename your directory from "Friendly Chat" to "FriendlyChat".

Comment: Did u add dependencies  "compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'" & "classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
"?

Comment: @AmitabhaBiswas Yes I have added them.

Answer (score 0):

@Iqra Make sure that the package name is same as that in json file

Comment: Yeah It is same

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error because your path contains a space char. 
`C:\Users\hp\AndroidStudioProjects\Friendly Chat\app\google-services.json`
As you can see there is space in `Friendly Chat`.

Kindly remove this space from directory name (project name) and paste `google-services.json` inside `app` directory.

One advice- "Never use a space character in any filename or module or directory name while developing any product".

Comment: Can you paste a screenshot of your project structure? something  like that - https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyBJS.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the configuration file from the developer's site and paste it in the app level directory of your project folder.

Answer (score 0):

It's

> google-services.json

not googleservices.json.

You are missing a hyphen in between 'google' and 'services'